# Будут ли освобождены ресурсы, если их закрыть таким образом

Tags: java, resources, try-catch

подскажите пожалуйста, есть класс, у класса есть поле private FileReader reader = ...;

будут ли освобождаться ресурсы, если я закрою их таким образом?

```
try(FileReader rederLink = this.reader) {
    //какая-то логика
} catch(Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Будут.

Только после этого, Вы уже не сможете использовать `this.reader` потому что он будет закрыт.